# How do I include all months when using MONTHNAME when some months have null data in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have sql query

```
select
    DISTINCT {fn MONTHNAME(entrydate)} AS monthname,
    emirate_name,
    location,
    price,
    bedroom 
from itf_property 
where 
    emirate_name='Dubai' 
    and location='JBR' 
    and bedroom='2' 
group by monthname 
order by id
```

I want to select the null month also from jan to dec like if jan have no value then it will show 0.

The output of above query is attached image

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: i am using mysql database

Answer (score 0):

Use if on mysql

```
select
DISTINCT {fn MONTHNAME(entrydate)} AS monthname,
emirate_name,
if(month is null, '0', month) as month, 
location,
price,
bedroom 
from itf_property 
where 
emirate_name='Dubai' 
and location='JBR' 
and bedroom='2' 
group by monthname 
order by id
```

Comment: @AkhileshSoni did you run this query? are you getting what you needed? I am using IF else check ..if the month is null it will return 0 else month

Comment: it will show the following error  "Unknown column 'month' in 'field list'

Comment: replace month with monthname as your column is month name @AkhileshSoni

Comment: yup, already replace with monthname after that this error show  #1054 - Unknown column 'monthname' in 'field list'